# Twig functions pasting as HTML in Craft CMS

Tags: php, twig, cpanel

I've installed Craft CMS and am in the process of making the HTML template of my site content manageable, I've done everything in Craft CMS and went to put the Twig include in index.html like the below:

`{% for module in entry.modules %} {% include '_modules/moduleText' %} {% endfor %}`

Instead of including the module content it pasted the above code as HTML which makes me think Twig isn't working at all, I've never used Craft CMS before - however when looking in the documentation it states Craft uses "Twig Primer" so it should be working out of the box right?

Does anyone know how to set Twig up to run with my Craft CMS site in C-Panel? - any info on what the directory structure should look like would be useful and whether I need to install Twig separately.

Image of my C-Panel Directory below, the Twig-2x.zip is just there incase I have to manually install Twig.

[image]

Comment: I found the Twig folder already inside Vendor so I'm pretty sure it should be working out of the box, I have absolutely no idea why none of my includes are working, is there anything required in my PHP Versions inside CPanel? I know I had to enable some things to get Craft working, anyone know if Twig has requirements too? version is 7.1

Comment: i suggest adding such question to dedicated craft cms stack exchange forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you may just have some files+folders in the wrong places...

Your `index.html` and the `modules` folder that you're including from should both be inside the `templates` folder, and your webserver should be serving from the `web` folder, which should have an `index.php` file in it still - is that how it all is at the moment?